# javascript: require('events').EventEmitter;

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

Why

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var channel = new EventEmitter();
```

works, but

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var channel = new EventEmitter();
```

does not work! Actually, I have another totally different example,

```
var Currency = require('./currency)
var Cu = new Currency();
```

works, but

```
var Currency = require('./currency).Currency;
var Cu = new Currency();
```

does not work. Here is my currency.js:

```
function Currency(canadianDollar) {
    this.canadianDollar = canadianDollar;
}

module.exports = Currency;

Currency.prototype.cal = function(amount) {
    return amount * this.canadianDollar;
}
```

Comment: Because they export different things.

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.22/lib/events.js#L38

Comment: if you want yours to be like events, module.exports = {Currency:Currency};

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is the way the API is written. A simplified example of "events" module would look like:

```
module.exports = {
    EventEmitter: function () {
        // ...
    }
};
```

In the above case `require('events');` would return an `Object` containing `EventEmitter`, but `require('events').EventEmitter` would return the actual EventEmitter function you are likely interested in instantiating.

Thought it would be good to mention that the API designer could indeed export the EventEmitter function directly with `module.exports = function () { ... };` however, they decided to leave space for other potentially useful properties of the "events" module.

**Edit**

Regarding `module.exports = EventEmitter;` in https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js, on the following lines you can find:

```
// Backwards-compat with node 0.10.x
EventEmitter.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
```

I suppose that starting from version 0.11 you can run `var Emitter = require('events');`, but in 0.10.x you are stuck with `require('events').EventEmitter`.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. But I checked events.js and found this: module.exports = EventEmitter; I think the constructor function is returned directly instead of an object containing the constructor function.

Comment: @Benson which `node --version` are you running? Take a look at my edit.

Comment: According to vkurchatkin's answer, I add a line Currency.Currency = Currency; to my currency.js. Both cases work. In events.js of version 10.25, module.exports = EventEmitter;

// Backwards-compat with node 0.10.x
EventEmitter.EventEmitter = EventEmitter; That means both cases should work too. But require('events') still does not work.

Comment: no, it's 0.11.something. Here is 0.10.25 https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.25-release/lib/events.js#L38

Answer (score 1):

`require` returns exactly what you put in `module.exports` object. So if you have `module.exports = Currency;` then `require` returns `Currency` and if you have `exports.Currency = Currency` `require` will return `{ Currency : Currency }` object.

if you want this to work both ways, just do `Currency.Currency = Currency; module.exports = Currency`. in latest node releases they do like this with `EventEmitter`

Comment: Thank you, vkurchatkin. That is my question. In events.js, module.exports = EventEmitter; but var EventEmitter = require('events');
var channel = new EventEmitter(); does not work.

Comment: try latest 0.11.x release

Comment: The current version is 0.10.25. I don't see any 0.11 release. May I know where I can find it?